# Using the appRouter in Backbone.MarionetteJS

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, routes, url-routing, marionette

I have been working with Backbone.Marionette recently and I'm running into some issues while trying to simulate a single-paged web application. I've created a [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z23uAE) that has a menu of dynamically generated list-items. My goal is to set up routing between the various menu items so I can change the content dynamically.

Just to see if it works I the console should log any activity within the router. Sadly nothing is happening and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. (Example of what I wish to achieve: [My previous test in AngularJS](http://plnkr.co/edit/m9LXip)).

I hope some more experienced Backbone users can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using a Marionette controller,  so change your RoutingAPI definition to this :

```
var RoutingAPI = Marionette.Controller.extend({
  home: function(){
     console.log("Page: 'home'."); 
  },
  news: function(){ 
     console.log("Page: 'news'."); 
  },
  about: function(){
     console.log("Page: 'about'.");
  },
  contact: function(){ 
     console.log("Page: 'contact'.");
  }
});
```

Define your router like this :

```
ApplicationRouter = Backbone.Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
   appRoutes: {
      "": "home",
      "home": "home",
      "news": "news",
      "about": "about",
      "contact": "contact"
   }
});
```

and use it like this

```
routingManager.router = new ApplicationRouter({controller :  new RoutingAPI()});
Backbone.history.start();
```

Notice that you were also missing the Backbone.history.start(); line.

Comment: Thank you very much, your suggestion works as a charm! My example was based on the sample book of MarionetteJS (which in my idea raised more questions then it answered).

Comment: Im glad I was able to help, try the Gentle introduction of Marionette a book by David Sulc

Comment: This is what I did. That's where I based my example on. This was however the free sample book.